# Pandas loc: Multiindexing and selecting rows with specific index values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe having 3 columns A B C

```
A B C
1 2 10
2 3 20
3 0 30
```

I have indexed column A,B and sorted

```
df = ( df.set_index([A,B]).sort_index())
```

I want to select rows with index A(1,2) and index B (2,3)

```
df1 = df.loc[[[1,2],[2,3]]]
```

It throws an error.. what am i doing wrong.. I did experiment with few other things and not able to come with a solution..

Comment: Column A(1,2,3) B(2,3,0) and C(10,20,30)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you use tuples, since that's how `MultiIndex` values are hashed (since lists cannot be hashed).

```
print(df.loc[[(1, 2), (2, 3)]])
      C
A B
1 2  10
2 3  20
```